# How to avoid a stop on warnings for a custom FreeBSD kernel compile?

Tags: kernel, freebsd

I am trying to compile my FreeBSD custom kernel, but I get warnings: for example about the initialization of certain variables. In normal circumstances I think such warnings shouldn't stop the compile process, but in FreeBSD they do!

How can I change the settings so the warnings don't stop the compiling of the FreeBSD kernel?

Comment: i searched the net and i found that deleting make.conf file can help .but when i deleted this file no improvement happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [Building FreeBSD](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BuildingFreeBSDWithClang) :

As of r233419, head should build without -Werror bailing out the build, e.g. there should be no unexpected warnings. If you are attempting to build something earlier, or encounter -Werror bailouts anyway, add the following to /etc/make.conf or /etc/src.conf, as appropriate:

```
# This setting to build world without -Werror:
NO_WERROR=
# This setting to build kernel without -Werror:
WERROR=
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Also I should mention that accepting is not for make Answers owner happy It works to help people find the true solutions :)

Comment: In my case, FreeBSD current, WERROR="-Wno-error" did the trick but it failed while linking the kernel. By the way has anyone able to build the kernel (v12) using GCC as against CLANG?